# Angularjs and articles

Tags: javascript, angularjs, article

What's the best way to implement long texts (let's say articles) into an Angular project? Preferably markdown. My articles contain rich text and images.

I'm pretty new to Angular, this could be a very basic function.

Comment: You mean something like https://github.com/btford/angular-markdown-directive ?

Comment: @ExplosionPills Read about it, but reading out external markdown files would keep my code cleaner, right?

Comment: Maybe you can do some fancy work with `ng-include`

Comment: @ExplosionPills That sounds nice! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of using ng-include:

```
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
  <select ng-model="article" ng-options="a.name for a in articles">
   <option value="">(blank)</option>
  </select>
  url of the article: <tt>{{article.url}}</tt>
  <hr/>
  <div class="slide-animate-container">
    <div class="slide-animate" ng-include="article.url"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
function Ctrl($scope) {
      $scope.articles =
        [ { name: 'article1.html', url: 'article1.html'},
          { name: 'article1.html', url: 'article1.html'} ];
      $scope.article = $scope.articles[0];
    }
```

article1.html

```
Extremely long article with <b>markup</b>
```

article2.html

```
Extremely long article with <b>markup</b>
```